# Paginating queries using DataAdapters

Tags: c#, sql, pagination, ado.net

I am trying to paginate my queries by using Data Adapter extension methods.

Here is what I have implemented so far:

```
public static PagingInformation ExecutePagingInformation(
    this IDbCommand dbCommand, int pageIndex, int pageSize,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    string oldCommandText = dbCommand.CommandText;
    dbCommand.CommandText = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ({dbCommand.CommandText}) Q";
    var totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(dbCommand.ExecuteScalar());
    dbCommand.CommandText = oldCommandText;

    return new PagingInformation(pageIndex, pageSize, 0, totalCount); 
}



public static DbDataReader ExecutePagedReader(
   this IDbCommand dbCommand, int pageIndex, int pageSize, 
   out PagingInformation pageInformation)
{
    if (dbCommand.CommandType != CommandType.Text)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only CommandType.Text is supported.");

    DbDataReader reader;
    if (dbCommand is OracleCommand oracleCommand)
    {
        pageInformation = dbCommand.ExecutePagingInformation(pageIndex, pageSize); //this is implemented by myself
        reader = oracleCommand.ExecutePageReader(CommandBehavior.Default, pageIndex * pageSize, pageSize); //this is native method
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }


    return reader;

}
```

then I am using them like

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecutePagedReader(pageIndex, pageSize, out pagingInformation))
{
    while (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
    {
        result.Add(reader[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

the problem is `$"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ({dbCommand.CommandText}) Q";` part which is subject to **SQL Injection**. I am considering to create another instance of SQLCommand and use parameterized query however, I am not sure that parameterized query can dynmaically create my inner query without escaping regular SQL (I guess this approach won't work)

Devart's DotConnect For Oracle has `OracleDataReader` which paginates results by using `ExecutePageReader`. I decompiled it and, as far as I understand, they are using StringBuilder to generate query which supports pagination. However, the code is obfurscated and I could not end up with solution.

Edit:

`$"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ({dbCommand.CommandText}) Q";`

`dbCommand.CommandText` is constructed by parameterized queries (no string concatenation)

Comment: Why would a Count(*) be subject to injection?  Where does dbCommand.CommandText come from ?

Comment: It's only vulnerable to SQL injection if you take unfiltered input and add it to the SQL.  If you're (correctly) using parameterised queries then you've already alleviated that concern anyway.    Any reason to not use an ORM?  You could just use `Skip()` and `Take()` to manage paging that way, though admittedly it would (probably) be more work to put the filter clauses together...

Comment: @GPW thank you for information. I am working on Legacy framework which includes dirty data and the database is not constrainted. Relationships are mostly logical. It is very hard to use EF, EF Core. I might consider using Dapper.

Comment: @Simonare EF is quite flexible;  you can override the conventions and if this is reporting on the data (so read only in effect) it shouldn't be too hard to implement.  I've put in place EF (though admittedly not EF Core) models etc. against a Firebird database (mostly designed 20 years ago) which has no foreign keys explicitly defined, Unique keys/joins are often based on string fields, Nothing is named 'Id' etc...  and it works well.